# Should I add @Inject for the function parameter which is from dependency injection?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm learning dependency injection, the following Code A is from the project https://github.com/android/sunflower

1: The parameter appDatabase of the function providePlantDao is from dependency injection, why doesn't author add @Inject before appDatabase just like Code B?

2: Is the Code C right?

**Code A**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
    }

    @Provides
    fun providePlantDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): PlantDao {
        return appDatabase.plantDao()
    }
     
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
    }

    @Provides
    fun providePlantDao(@Inject appDatabase: AppDatabase): PlantDao {
        return appDatabase.plantDao()
    }
     
    ...
}
```

**Code C**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
    }

    @Provides
    fun providePlantDao(): PlantDao {
        @Inject lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase
        return appDatabase.plantDao()
    }
     
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `@Inject` is only needed when one wants to provide a dependency via field injection. Not only is it not possible inside functions, but you have to read the code the following:

> @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) @Module class DatabaseModule

With this, you tell hilt that you want to create a new module that should be installed in the `SingleletonComponent` Graph. So every dependency provided inside this module is available to the entire application.

> ```
> @Singleton
> @Provides
> fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase
> ```

Now you tell hilt, that you want to provide a dependency annotated with `@Singleton` and therefore it should be created once / always provide the same instance. Furthermore, you tell hilt, how to create an instance of `AppDatabase`, so at this point dagger hilt knows: "Ha, now I know how to create an AppDatabase and every time the programmer needs an AppDatabase, I will provide the same instance!"

> ```
> @Provides
> fun providePlantDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): PlantDao
> ```

Now you tell hilt how to provide an instance of `PlantDao`. You don't need to manually inject an `AppDatabase` nor write `@Inject` because you already told hilt how to create an AppDatabase!

Comment: @HelloCW no, code A is as explained above. You can't use `@Inject` inside a function