# How can I use dependency injection in CoroutineWorker with hilt?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm learning dependency injection, the following Code A and Code B are from the project https://github.com/android/sunflower

The author has defined a dependency injection `PlantDao` in Code A, but a `PlantDao` object is created with code `database.plantDao()` manually in Code B.

Why doesn't the author use dependency injection with the object `PlantDao` in Code B?  How can I use dependency injection with the object `PlantDao` in Code B?

**Code A**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
    }

    @Provides
    fun providePlantDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): PlantDao {
        return appDatabase.plantDao()
    }

   ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
class SeedDatabaseWorker(
        context: Context,
        workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val filename = inputData.getString(KEY_FILENAME)
            if (filename != null) {
                applicationContext.assets.open(filename).use { inputStream ->
                    JsonReader(inputStream.reader()).use { jsonReader ->
                        ...
                        val database = AppDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)
                        database.plantDao().insertAll(plantList)

                        ...
            } else {
               ...
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
           ...
        }
    }

    ..
}
```

**Added Content**

To Andrew: Thanks!

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124252/should-i-add-inject-for-the-function-parameter-which-is-from-dependency-injecti), you told me that `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` will be available to the entire application, you can see Image 1.

The author has defined a dependency injection object of `PlantDao` in Code A and install it as `SingletonComponent::class`.

So I think that the object of `PlantDao` will be available to the entire application，why can't I use the dependency injection object of PlantDao directly in Code B?

**Image 1**
[image]

**Code D**

```
class SeedDatabaseWorker @Inject  constructor(
    database: AppDatabase,
    context: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val filename = inputData.getString(KEY_FILENAME)
            if (filename != null) {
                applicationContext.assets.open(filename).use { inputStream ->
                    JsonReader(inputStream.reader()).use { jsonReader ->
                        ...                  
                        database.plantDao().insertAll(plantList)
                        ...
                    } else {   
                ..
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to annotate your worker with `@HiltWorker`, your context and params with `@Assisted`, your constructor with `@AssistedInject` and then you can constructor inject your dao.

### WorkerCode

```
@HiltWorker
class SeedDatabaseWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
        @Assisted context: Context,
        @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
        private val database: AppDatabase
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val filename = inputData.getString(KEY_FILENAME)
            if (filename != null) {
                applicationContext.assets.open(filename).use { inputStream ->
                    JsonReader(inputStream.reader()).use { jsonReader ->
                        ...
                        database.plantDao().insertAll(plantList)

                        ...
            } else {
               ...
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
           ...
        }
    }

    ..
}
```

Furthermore, you have to change the default WorkerFactory to a hiltWorkerFactory and remove the default initializer:

### AppCode

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class ExampleApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

  @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

  override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
      Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

### Needed Dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
```

Be aware that some processes change when later updating androidx.work to 2.6. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack)

### Edit

You can use your dependency injection plantdao directly in code b. That's what `private val database: AppDatabase` inside your constructor means. In the first step, you provided your plantdao to hilt and told it how to create an instance of plantdao. In the next step (code b), you retain an instance of your plantdao via constructor injecting it. You have to first provide it to hilt (via a module) and then you can retain it (via constructor injection).

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Thank you very much!   Do you mean I should use such as Code D in my edited question for dependency injection with constructor?

Comment: @HelloCW yes exactly.